# Reporting Services Action Go To Report issue finding report in different folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to write SSRS reports on my PC (Win 7 32-bit, if relevant?) for deployment to a standalone SSRS (non-Sharepoint).

I have written a report in "Report Project1" folder and when the user clicks on a textbox I would like to open a report that exists in a different folder (let's call it "Live").

In the Text Box Properties dialog box I have selected Action and clicked the Go to report button. I'm not to sure what to put under Specify a report?

If I put /Live/report2 then I get error "Could not find a part of the path 'H:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Report Project1\Report Project1\bin\Debug\Live\report2.rdl'."

If I put ../Live/report2 (Live and Report Project1 are at same level) then I get the same error.

If I put http://< servername >/ReportServer/Live/report2 then I get the error "The given path's format is not supported."

Can anybody put me right?

Answer (score 0):

Try `/Reports/Live/report2`

If you specify a full path on a report server running in native mode, you must give it the path from the Home folder. 
Here's a helpful link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220423.aspx

Otherwise, you can achieve the same goal by using the go to url action.  Just provide it the url to the subreport and send your parameters as part of the url.

Comment: Thanks for trying, unfortunately it just gives me the first error (with Reports/Live/Report2 at the end of the path). I'm thinking that maybe there is somewhere I need to specify where it should look for reports, rather than the default area.

Comment: You can also try using the go to url action (I ammended my answer to show this as well) if you can't figure out the go to report.  I don't know that you can change where it looks.  With what I gave you, if you have your report server configured correctly, you shouldn't have to.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, Go to URL works fine for me. As I'm new to SSRS I am trying out all the functionality and thought Go to report might be easier to use going fwd - but not if I can't get it to work! ;)  For Go to URL I use something like this: ="javascript:void(window.open('http://< server name >/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Live/Report2 Actual Name Has Spaces&LearnerID=" & mid(Fields!StudentName.Value,instr(Fields!StudentName.Value,"(")+1,6) & "&Year=" & First(Fields!CollegeYear.Value, "qGetCurrentAcademicYear") & "&Session=" & Fields!WeekNo.Value & "','_blank'))"